# How to let users add cell into a custom position of a tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, tableview

I'm looking for design examples (frontend) of how to let the users add an item in 'Edit' mode in any position they want in a tableview. This is for a iPhone/iPad universal checklist app I'm creating.

At the moment I can only find examples where new items are added in the top or bottom, and then moving them around. But non where the user can specify the insert position of the new item.

I was thinking of letting the users select a row and then the new item would be inserted below it. The problem with this option is that I also want the 'tap a row' functionality to be reserved for entering an expanded edit mode (which pushes a different view), where the user can edit the details of the checklist item.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: The main idea is that when you are giving user to select a row under which new cell should go will work only if you insert that data in your array at that particular index ex: user select 2nd row so now you should add new data in 3 index of your data array and reload the table

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm actually looking for a front-end design solution. How would the app let the user choose a position to insert the new row, while still allowing them to tap a row to enter a 'detail edit' view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a ">"-shaped button off to the left or right between each cell that you can tap to insert one there?

Some apps also let you pinch two cells apart to have a new cell appear at that position.